# Issue Storing "Favourite" button state in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

Not sure why my button state is not being stored. The image changes from unfilled to filled however when I click out of the view controller and back in it is reset to unfilled.

```
var recipeFav = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "recipeFav")

@IBAction func FavButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        if recipeFav {
            let image = UIImage(named: "starNonfill")
            (sender as AnyObject).setImage(image, for: .normal)
        } else {
            let image = UIImage(named: "starFilled")
            (sender as AnyObject).setImage(image, for: .normal)
        }

        recipeFav = !recipeFav
        UserDefaults.standard.set(recipeFav, forKey: "recipeFav")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you don't seem to have any code that sets the button image based on the boolean when the view appears - you retrieve it from user defaults but only set the image once the user taps on the button.

You can make a few other changes too:

- By convention, in Swift, functions and properties start with a lower case letter - this helps you distinguish them from types.
- You can declare your action function as receiving `sender` as a `UIButton`, avoiding the need to downcast.
- You can use `.toggle()` to toggle a boolean
- You don't need to call `synchronize()`.

I would refactor the image setting into its own function and use a `didSet` handler to call it and save the boolean whenever the value changes.  You also need to fetch the current value from `viewDidAppear` to ensure the initial state is set correctly.

```
var recipeFav = false {
    didSet {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(recipeFav,forKey:"recipeFav")
        self.updateFavouriteButton()
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var favouriteButton: UIButton!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.recipeFav = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey:"recipeFav")
}

@IBAction func favButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.recipeFav.toggle()
}

private func updateFavouriteButton() {
    let image = self.recipeFav ? UIImage(named: "starNonfill") : UIImage(named: "starFilled")
    self.favouriteButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
}
```